# Firebase HTTP to HTTPS NGINX redirect for custom domains dropping POST method for GET

Tags: firebase, express, nginx, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

Firebase fails to redirect any HTTP POST requests to HTTPS POST. EX:

POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: apis.mydomain.com

is redirected by Firebase NGINX to

GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: apis.mydomain.com

if you are explicit about https, then NGINX works properly: POST -> POST

So, when the request hits Firebase hosting, and redirects your request to a firebase function that can be accessed by an https endpoint, the method has the possibility of collapsing into a GET from a POST method.

Looking closer at the headers, inside the Firebase Cloud Function, the protocol always expresses as http, instead of https.

I'm assuming this is an internal issue that I cannot modify, however, this is an issue for what I am doing, and this definitely is a problem given I cannot modify the NGINX that is handling my http(s) requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you redirect with a 301 or 302 status code, the POST is downgraded to GET.

You need to use a 307 status to maintain POST across the redirect. See [this document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) for details.

On Nginx, you will need to use a `return` statement. For example:

```
return 307 https://$host$request_uri;
```

Comment: That’s the problem: I am using firebase to capture post requests made by an api. For this specific use case-it works because I can just treat all requests made as post or get. But internally, if I were to use firebase for another purpose, where I cannot control who does what when they request from my endpoint, I cannot alter the way nginx is used internally by firebase. I cannot modify the way firebase works internally. I want to know if this is intentional or if this is a bug by firebase

Comment: You would have to reach out to Firebase support for that info.